# foreman with custom buildpack

Tags: heroku, foreman

How do I get my heroku app to run locally with foreman if I'm using a custom buildpack?  I'm using a nginx/php-fpm build pack (https://github.com/travisj/heroku-buildpack-nginx-php) which installs php and nginx and then starts all the processes.

How do I get that to run with foreman?  There's no --buildpack option that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and I even started rolling my own code as an answer. Finally, though, I actually searched through the issues logged on the foreman github repo and discovered the existence of:

https://github.com/ddollar/mason

Although, when I used it, I quickly ran into a Ruby bug that caused my builds to fail. [@clowder's pull request](https://github.com/ddollar/mason/pull/13) half-fixed the problem, so I went ahead and followed [@andys](https://github.com/andys)'s suggestion there and implemented the rest of the fix:

https://github.com/steven-collins-omega/mason/tree/fix-symlink-copying

That seems to do the trick. Good luck!